# Vagrant boxes gives SSH error when trying to connect

Tags: ssh, vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows, vagrant-provision

I'm trying to create 3 ubuntu vagrant boxes: machine1,machine2,machine3.
machine3 should run an ansible playbook which installs something on machine1 and machine2.
However, keep getting an error when trying to ssh (ssh vagrant@192.168.77.21 -p 2221)to the machines:

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.77.21 port 2221: Connection refused
```

This is the Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  $script = <<-SCRIPT
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt install software-properties-common
  sudo add-apt-repository --yes --update ppa:ansible/ansible
  sudo apt -y install ansible
  ansible --version
  SCRIPT

  N = 3
  VAGRANT_VM_PROVIDER = "virtualbox"

  (1..N).each do |machine_id|
    config.vm.define "machine#{machine_id}" do |machine|
      machine.vm.box="ubuntu/trusty64"
      machine.vm.hostname = "machine#{machine_id}"
      machine.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.77.#{20+machine_id}"
      machine.vm.network "forwarded_port", id: "ssh", guest: 22, host: 2220+machine_id
      machine.vm.synced_folder ".", "/home/vagrant/data"
      # Only execute once on the Ansible provisioner,
      # when all the machines are up and ready.
      if machine_id == N
        machine.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script
        machine.vm.provision "shell",
          inline: "sudo cp /home/vagrant/data/hosts /etc/ansible/hosts"
        machine.vm.provision "shell",
          inline: "ansible-playbook /home/vagrant/data/playbook.yml -vvv"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: ansible all -m ping
machine1 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 192.168.77.21 port 2221: Connection refused",
    "unreachable": true
}
machine2 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 192.168.77.22 port 2222: Connection refused",
    "unreachable": true

Comment: Have you tried ssh'ing those machines "by hand" — meaning outside of Ansible? Does it work?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε
yes, vagrant ssh machine1 and vagrant ssh machine2 work.

Comment: Can you try ssh vagrant@192.168.77.21 -p 2221 and see if that works?

Comment: getting ssh: connect to host 192.168.77.21 port 2221: Connection refused

Comment: So, @Yael your issue has nothing to do with Ansible but with the way you are provisioned your SSH keys on your vagrant box.

Comment: You should re focus this question by [edit]ing it and ask yourself why ssh'ing to that vagrant box is not possible before bringing any Ansible playbook in the matter.